# Do I need to repeat past perfect in two consecutive sentences describing the same event?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

If I write the first sentence using both past simple and past perfect, and then in the next sentence I want to speak about the action described by past perfect in the first sentence, do I need to use past perfect again or is it OK to shift to past simple?

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: I do not have any exact examples; I wonder how it should be according to the rules.

Comment: It's difficult to envisage what you mean if you don't provide examples.  You can't expect people to invent sentences that fit the condition you want to ask about.

Comment: OK, for example: The company was developing a technology that it had earliear bought  from an independent entrepreneur. The entrepreneur sold/had sold the technology at an auction.

Comment: Yes, the second sentence needs to be past perfect. The company _had bought_ the technology, and the entrepreneur _had sold_ it, before the time when it was being developed.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is that you shouldn’t ever really consider shifting tenses between connected sentences. Past simple tense refers to a different timeframe (more specific, to be exact) than past perfect, and so switching between them to refer to the same action doesn’t make sense.

For example,

> I had just finished preparing ingredients for Thanksgiving dinner when my sister called me. I had been working on those ingredients all day.

In this sentence, “had finished” is past perfect, “called” is past simple, and “had been working” is past perfect. To indicate which ideas are connected, you have to make sure their tenses match. If I had said,

> I had just finished preparing ingredients for Thanksgiving dinner when my sister called me. I worked on those ingredients all day.

Now it’s unclear when exactly I was working on the ingredients. Was it after my sister called, or before? In fact, now it’s no longer clear when “all day” was. It could be the week after Thanksgiving, for all we know.